# Check for data existence in multiple tables

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, sqlperformance

To check for an Id existence in multiple tables (10 - 15 tables) what will be best option? In point of performance.

1. Using Joins
2. Using individual query for each table (called from DAO of Spring).
3. Using exists.

Need to take decisions based on existence of Id from multiple tables.

Comment: What are the results you want?  Do you want to know the table it is in, or just if its in any of the tables or if its in all the tables?

Comment: more data of the schema pls :S

Comment: I just want to check a value exists in many tables. Need a value passed as parameter from java exists in tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure performance between querys in oracle with explain plan ( using Oracle sql developer for example ), and write some simple java class to see how long this takes comparing with DAO's.

When you use exists Oracle will use your pk and fk indexes and you will do it all in one query inside the database. I think this is the best option but if you compare them all you will have the accurate option.

Answer (score 0):

Using UNION ALL:

```
SELECT 'table1' FROM table1 WHERE id = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2' FROM table2 WHERE id = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table3' FROM table3 WHERE id = ?
```

Another solutions is using functions:

```
select function(id)
```

This solutions make a trip to the database server.